# Image File Upload using Axios in React Native App PHP backend

Tags: php, react-native, image, file-upload, axios

I'm using axios to try to post formdata including an image from a react native app:

```
   data.append("image", {
            name: "image1",
            type: "image/jpeg",
            file_upload:  file
        });
```

I get this on server side:

```
 ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_parts"]=>
    array(5) {
         ....
    [4]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "image"
        [1]=>
        array(3) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(6) "image1"
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "image/jpeg"
          ["file_upload"]=>
          array(5) {
            ["height"]=>
            int(3024)
            ["uri"]=>
            string(324) "file:///Users/joe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/790...9C/data/Containers/Data/Application/6B54B...27C/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FProj-f2...E61.jpg"
            ["type"]=>
            string(5) "image"
            ["width"]=>
            int(4032)
            ["cancelled"]=>
            bool(false)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to test if I have a file using:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($obj['data']['_parts'][4]){}
```

or

```
if(is_uploaded_file($obj['data']['_parts'][4][1]['file_uplaod'])){}
```

Both return false.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong- whether it's on the posting side or whether I'm not grabbing the file correctly

Edit:

I'm grabbing what's being posted like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);


$post_image= $obj['data']['_parts'][4][1]['file_upload'];
```

Seems to work for all the other fields

Edit 2:

I check this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

echo "post method";

}
            if ($_FILES) {

              echo "files exist";

            }
            else{
              echo "no files";
            }
```

I get post method is true but no files

Comment: How is this array being created on the server side in the first place? This doesn’t look like a normal structure that `is_uploaded_file` is intended to be used with, specifically `$_FILES`.

Comment: Good question, please see the edits above

Comment: That's the right clue, I found this comment: php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data". I'm not sure how to correctly pull the image file data

Comment: I think I got it working using fetch, not sure if theres a way with axios